# HTML: <li> tag not allowed as child of <nav> What's an alternative?

Tags: html, css

This is probably child's play to anyone who actually knows what they're doing (but I'm completely self-taught so I need a little help).

The site: http://www.sandhtestsite.kaylynnehatch.com

The W3 HTML Validator keeps returning this error: 
"Element li not allowed as child of element nav in this context."

This is my nav code:

```
  <nav id="mainav" class="clear"> 
  <li class="active">
      <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="/trademark-services.html">Trademark Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Problem is, I'm not sure how else to set this up. If I remove the li tags (and related CSS), how do I get them to display properly AND still work responsively with mobile?

Comment: wrap the `<li></li>` elements in `<ul></ul>` ?   UL = Unordered List, LI = List Item... think about what you wrote...

Comment: I believe a list item (`li`) should be a child of either an ordered list (`ol`) or unordered list (`ul`).  Either can be a child of `nav`.  So, your code has a closing `ul` misplaced - that should be an issue for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list item (`li`) should be a child of either an ordered list (`ol`) or unordered list (`ul`). Either can be a child of `nav`.

In your code, you have a closing `ul` misplaced - that would be an issue for validation.

So, try using an unordered list around your list items.

```
<nav id="mainav" class="clear"> 
  <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="/trademark-services.html">Trademark Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Oh, crap - you're totally right! I completely forgot my 'ol' tags. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your Lis in a ol or ul tag.

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainav" class="clear">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/trademark-services.html">Trademark Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes i see. I just really copied his code. I didn't realize there were so many issues in his HTML other than he didn't wrap the LIs in a proper parent. Wow lots of down votes there.

Comment: Man people are brutal with the down votes. =[ I did answer the question he asked. Just didn't realize he had so many mistakes in his originally posted HTML.

Comment: =O sorry. Just an automatic thing I type I suppose. Apologies.

Comment: No worries. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `<li>` elements should be children of `<ul>` or `<ol>`elements. In your case, you have improper formatting, thus making it seem you are missing the `<ul>`
write it like this instead:

```
<nav id="mainav" class="clear">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/trademark-services.html">Trademark Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp

Comment: The open `li` was probably meant to be the missing `ul`...  `<ul class="active">`

Comment: Oh, crap - you're totally right! I completely forgot my 'ul' tags. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score -2):

You're opening one tag type of item and then closing a different item. Open and close tags need to be a 1:1 relationship. It should look more like this:

```
<nav id="mainav" class="clear"> 
  <ul> 
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/trademark-services.html">Trademark Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/attorneys.html">Attorneys</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Haha -- you're right. I wasn't paying enough attention.